# How to import java class that is in the generated folder?

Tags: java, build, protocol-buffers

So basically I'm using protobuf. Protobuf enables me to generate java code (.java files) thanks to the protobuf-plugin (gradle). 
My problem is that the code is generated in the build -> generated -> source -> proto -> main -> java and I struggle to import the code that has been generated in my actual code (located in the src folder).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNAoL.png)

Comment: What build system are you using: Maven? Gradle?

Comment: Why does it need to be in the "src" Folder at all? Can't you add "build/source/proto/main/java" to the build path as well? This would probably depend on your used IDE. In eclipse it is possible to use multiple source folders. Can't speak for other IDEs. The advantage of this setup would be, that all generated code would be in one folder, while human written code would be in another. Dividing it this way is usually a good idea. If you happen to use eclipse, right click the ...proto/main/java folder and click on "Build path > use as source folder".

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I'm using Gradle.

Comment: @TreffnonX actually I don't want it to be in my src folder. I just want to be able to import the code so I can use the code from the generated class in the classes located in the src folder. It really is an import problem. BTW I'm using IntelliJ.

Comment: @N.Gamlin then I'd suggest you add the folder as source folder. This automatically leads to the result you want. You may have to add it to the "reexport" list as well, if other projects depend on this one.

Comment: Generally speaking, the plugin _should_ be responsible for adding its generated-sources root as a source folder.

Comment: Just added an image. Don't know if it will help understand my problem.

Comment: First try to re-import gradle project. Pls share your build.gradle. Have you applied idea plugin?